# SwiftLint: how to configure rule severity for a rule with warning and error configurations

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I would like to configure the Swiftlint [`cyclomatic_complexity`](https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/cyclomatic_complexity.html) rule to always have the severity level of warning.

Here are the approaches I have tried in the `.swiftlint.yml`.

```
cyclomatic_complexity: warning
```

```
cyclomatic_complexity: 
  severity: warning
```

Both of these yield the same result. Namely, upon running `swiftlint`, before linting it prints the following error.

`Invalid configuration for 'cyclomatic_complexity'. Falling back to default.`

How do you configure the severity of this rule for `swiftlint`, so that it only generates warnings and not errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```yaml
# .swiftlint.yml
cyclomatic_complexity: 20
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, please add an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try this in .swiftlint.yml, it works for me:

```
cyclomatic_complexity:
warning: 10
error: 20
```

Comment: This is the default configuration. It generates an error for complexity over 20. I would like it to generate a warning even if the complexity is over 20.

Comment: Yes, it's default, but you can set if you want warning to 30 and error to 50.